# Proper Way to Shift Integer Into List Index Range

Tags: python, list

I need to retrieve the item at index `i` from list `l`. However, sometimes `i` falls outside of the range of the list index and throws an `IndexError`. I need to shift `i` to always be inside the range of the list index **by leaps of `len(l)`**. The following code achieves just that.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

i = 6

while i >= len(l):
    i -= len(l)
while i < 0:
    i += len(l)

item = l[i] # item = 'b'
```

For my use case, `i` never falls more than `len(l)` out of range in either direction, so I'm able to shorten to this one liner by using `if` statements instead of `while` statements.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

i = -3

i = i-len(l) if i >= len(l) else i+len(l) if i < 0 else i

item = l[i] # item = 'c'
```

I'm thinking there must be some builtin function that achieves just this result, without a long, logical sentence. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: @0x5453 that does't work when you get farther than `2*len(l)`, but it does within the constraints of the question.  Nicely done!

Comment: @MarkRansom: Can you provide a concrete example of where this fails?

Comment: @0x545 Your solution works perfectly for my use case. Feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: @ScottHunter my comment was based on a misunderstanding of the question. Ignore it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a perfect use case for the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

```
item = l[i % len(l)]
```

Answer (score -2):

No, there's no built-in function to do this.  But it's simple to create one.

```
def clamp(x, size):
    return max(0, min(x, size-1))
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I need to shift it by the length of the list,  not just bring it into range. This solution turns every number below range into 0 and every number above range into the length of the list.

Comment: @MillerTime yes indeed I misunderstood the question.  That's such an odd behavior that I don't understand how you thought there might be a function for it.

Comment: Isn't it just modulo maths? Like 26 o'clock is 2 o'clock modulo 24.

Answer (score -3):

How about `i = max(0, min(i, len(lst)-1))`

```py
lst = list(range(5))

i = 25
i = max(0, min(i, len(lst)-1))
print(lst[i])

i = -25
i = max(0, min(i, len(lst)-1))
print(lst[i])
```

**Output**

```
4
0
```